# Ошибка H20 heroku при работе python telegram бота

Tags: python, telegram, heroku

Задеплоил телеграмм бота на Heroku, но он не заработал и в логах появилась ошибка: `at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=calm-dawn-72046.herokuapp.com request_id=0c7c848b-8a11-46d8-a2f1-d87936695f50 fwd="95.72.48.181" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https` 
Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: Сие [означает](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/45), что за 75 секунд ваше приложение так и не запустилось. Возможно упало где-то по пути.

Comment: На локалке вроде запускалось.

Comment: Теперь ошибка поменялась на тип H10

Comment: [H10](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed) - это уже чистый крэш.

Comment: А в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Бот должен принимать текстовые сообщения пока идут только они всё нормально, однако если отправить не текстовое сообщение то бот крашеца.

Comment: Я попробовал его предеплоить однако он крашиться через минуту при этом до краша всё прекрасно работает.